# Undefined method MongoCollection::command() when trying to get unique records from DB

Tags: php, mongodb, cursor, distinct

I am getting the following error 
`Fatal error: Call to undefined method MongoCollection::command() in /home/cr47/public_html/methods.php on line 67` when I try to get unique records from the MongoDB I am working with.

I have the code listing all of my records correctly but I don't want to list duplicates.  So I changed my list Records function from this(works but lists "Butter" 20 times instead of once):

```
public function listRecords($query = null){
    $this->find($query);

    foreach($this->cursor as $record) {
        $ing = $record['Shrt_Desc'];

        echo '<a href="find.php?Shrt_Desc=' . $ing .'"> ' . $ing . ' </a> </br>';

    }
}
```

I modified the above function(in an attempt to make "Butter" only list once):

```
public function listRecords($query = null){
    $this->find($query);
    foreach($this->cursor as $record) {
        //$ing = $record['Shrt_Desc'];
        $ing = $this->command(array("distinct" => "record", "key" => "Shrt_Desc"));
        echo '<a href="find.php?Shrt_Desc=' . $ing .'"> ' . $ing . ' </a> </br>';
    }
}
```

Here is the `distinct.php` page where I instantiate my classes and call my functions:

```
        include ("methods.php");
        $csvCommands = new csvCommands();
        $csvCommands->listRecords();
```

Comment: I should also add that I have a database class that handles mongo connection, db naming, and defining the find query:
 protected function find($query = null){
  if ($query == null){
   $this->cursor = $this->collection->find();
  }
  else{
   $this->cursor = $this->collection->find($query);
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are calling `$this->find($query)` are you sure you have a method called `find` or you are trying to call MongoDB find method it should be something like `$this->db->find` or `$this->mongoDB->find`

I think is better to upload your full call so that we can look at it better if you are still having issues

**Edit 1**

Replace

```
$this->command
```

With

```
$this->connection->command
```

Thanks

:)

Comment: Yes I have the find method defined, made a comment on the question with it.

Comment: The find part works fine.  It's the distinct part that does not.

Comment: Please see http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php ..... and see my edited answer

Comment: I tried 

$this->connection->command

$this->connection->collection->command

$this->collection->command

nothing seemed to work

Answer (score 0):

I just tried as part of MongoDB training... It works.. Below my thinks

```
$client = new MongoClient();

if($client){

/*echo "connection successufull";*/
$dbs=$client->school;
$studentcol=$dbs->students;
$lowest=[];
$scores=$studentcol->find();
foreach($scores as $score)
{
    $id=$score["_id"];
    $scoreslist=$score["scores"];
    var_dump($scoreslist)."</br>";
    $updated_sco=setnew_scores($scoreslist);
    echo "</br>";
    var_dump($updated_sco)."</br>";
    $update=update_score($studentcol,$id,$updated_sco);
    echo "old score list =>" .$scoreslist. " new score list is ".$updated_sco;

}
}

else
echo "connection un successfull";
?>
<?php
function setnew_scores($score)
{
    $counts=count($score);
    $counts;
    for ($i=0;$i<$counts;$i++)
    {
        if($score[$i]["type"] == "homework")
        {
            $lowest[$i]=$score[$i]["score"];    
        }

    }
    $lower = min($lowest);
    $j=0;
    for($i=0;$i<$counts;$i++)
    {   

        /*echo "</br> Type: ".$score[$i]["type"]."</br>";
        echo "</br> Scores: ".$score[$i]["score"]."</br>";
        echo "lower: ".$lower."</br>";*/
        if($score[$i]["score"] !=$lower ||  $score[$i]["type"]!=="homework")
        {
            $updated_scores[$j]["type"]=$score[$i]["type"];
            //echo $updated_scores[$j]["type"];
            $updated_scores[$j]["score"]=$score[$i]["score"];
            $j++;
        }
    }
    echo "</br>";   
    //print_r( $updated_scores)."</br>";
    return $updated_scores;
}
function update_score($scores,$id,$newscore)
{
    //print_r($newscore);/* its an array content*/
/*i tried the below type also its also works fine*/
    /*$newss="";
    for($i=0;$i<count($newscore);$i++)
    {
        $newss.="[\"".$newscore[$i]["type"]."\":".$newscore[$i]["score"]."]";
    }
    //echo $newss;
    //echo "</br>update([\"_id\":".$id."],['\$set'=>['scores' => ".$newss."]])";*/
    try{

        //$scores->update(["_id"=>$id],['$set'=>['scores' => $newss]]);
        $scores->update(["_id"=>$id],['$set'=>['scores' => $newscore]]);
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->get_Message();
    }
}
```